# mocking bootstrap datepicker in jasmine

Tags: angularjs-directive, jasmine, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to access datepicker onClose method via mocking its not working.i have injected all required bootstrap module in spec file

```
define(['angular', 'app'], function(angular, myApp) {
myApp.directive('customdate', function() {
    var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        element.datepicker({
            dateFormat: attrs.format || 'yy/mm/dd',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            onClose: function(date) {
                if (attrs.datetype === 'fromField') {
                    var elem = angular.element('#' + attrs.todateid);
                    elem.datepicker("option", "minDate", date).datepicker('setDate', date).focus();
                    var toDate = date || '';
                    scope.dateRange[attrs.todateid] = toDate;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        elem.datepicker('show')
                    }, 0);
                }
            }
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: linkFn
    };
});});
```

and in spec file i m trying to validate directive which is using datepicker in link function

```
define(
['jquery', 'angular', 'app', 'uiBootstrap',
    'datepicker_drtv'
],
function() {
    'use strict';
    describe('Test Suit', function() {
        var datePickerElement;
        var $compile, $rootScope, scope;
        var tpl;


        beforeEach(function() {
            angular.mock.module('myApp');
            angular.mock.inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_) {
                $compile = _$compile_;
                $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
                scope = $rootScope.$new();


            });
        });

        it('- check initial setup', function() {
            scope.startDate = '2016-09-29T00:00:00.000+0000';
            tpl = "<input type='text' id='startdateFrom' customdate datetype='fromField' todateid='startdateTo' class='fromTxt' ng-model='startDate' readonly />";
            var element = $compile(tpl)(scope);
            scope.$digest();
            element.val(scope.startDate).trigger("input");

            element.datepicker('option', 'onClose');
            var eVal = element.val();

            expect(angular.element(element).val()).toEqual(eVal);
        });

    });
});
```

test case is not failing  but in coverage report, link function is not covering